# Javascript: Passing unknown params to call back function

Tags: javascript

I have a generic form checker, and once validated it needs to handoff to a callback function to process the form, I'm stuck at getting the required form fields over to the callback function.

Requirements:
- checkForm needs to be generic
- Form fields need to be passed to the callback function (updateSection() in this case)

Any ideas?

Current code below...

HTML Forrm:

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:checkForm(0,updateSection(), event); return false;">
    <h2>Update Section</h2>
    <p><?php echo $partsAvailable; ?></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="sectionTitle" placeholder="Title" /></p>
    <p><textarea id="sectionContent" placeholder="Content"></textarea></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Update</button></p>
</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var allGood = false;

// General form checker
function checkForm(which, callback, evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // We need to check a form to make sure nothing is missed
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[which];
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var allGood = false;

    for(var i = 0; i  < rows.length-1; i++) {

        if(!getVal(rows[i].childNodes[0].id)) {
            allGood = false;
        }else{
            allGood = true;
        }
    }

    if(allGood == true)  callback();

    return false;
}

// Getting values from inputs
function getVal(el) {
    val = '';

    switch(el.type) {
        case 'text':
            val = document.getElementById(el).value;
            break;

        case 'select':
            val = document.getElementById(el).options[document.getElementById(el).selectedIndex].value;
            break;

        default:
            val = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    }

    return val;
}

function updateSection(part, title, content) {
    alert('Function called');

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass `callback` function to `checkForm()` should be like this.

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:checkForm(0,updateSection, event); return false;">
```

Store `return` from `getVal()` in a local variable. And pass value to `updateSection()` from where invoke the callback function.

```
var temp = [];
for(var i = 0; i  < rows.length-1; i++) {
    if(!getVal(rows[i].childNodes[0].id)) {
        allGood = false;
    }else{
        temp.push(getVal(rows[i].childNodes[0].id);
        allGood = true;
    }
}

if(allGood == true)  callback(temp); // passing all form value as temp array.
```